# Access array elements in object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array as part of an object whose elements I need to access. However, everything a tried so far failed. Could you give me any hints? Thanks!
Here is the object shown with `console.dir (data)` which is the object:

```
[Log] Object (main.chunk.js, line 743)

networkData: Array (1)
  0 Array (2)
    0 Object

      __typename: "networkDat"

      source: 2

      target: 1

   Object Prototyp
 1 Object

      __typename: "networkDat"

      source: 1274

      target: 3

   Object Prototyp

  Array Prototyp

 Array Prototyp

Object Prototyp
```

In particular, I need to access the "source" and "target" values.

Comment: What you've posted is just a console dump. Please post your `networkData` object in JSON.

Comment: It depends on what you want to access, the object seems to have a `networkData` that has as value an array of arrays. To access the array of arrays you can use `data.networkData`, to access the first element in the inner array (this array has only one element) you could use `data.networkData[0]`.

Comment: Here is the JSON format:
{"networkData":[[{"source":2,"target":1,"__typename":"networkDat"},{"source":1274,"target":3,"__typename":"networkDat"}]]}

Comment: I tried data.networkData[0] but it gives me "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.networkData')"